# Docker Swarms and Stacks: What's the difference?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I just read Docker's excellent [Getting Started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) guide, and just wanted to confirm I understand the basic Docker parlance before I go much further. These definitions are *somewhat* provided in the docs, but a lot of those docs are example-based without giving concrete form to the following concepts.

As such, my *understanding* is that:

- **Services**: Docker Services are the different components of your application: the frontend might be a React UI, the backend might be a Spring Boot web service, you might have a MySQL DB as well as a RabbitMQ broker; these would all be different *Services* all comprising your application.
- **Cluster**: Docker Clusters are when you have a Swarm managing 1+ Services for an application across 2+ Docker Hosts; the Cluster simply refers to all the Docker Hosts where your Service containers are running.
- **Compose**: Docker Compose is a tool used to manage Services, Swarms and Stacks.
- **Stack**: Docker Stacks occur when a Swarm Manager is managing **multiple Swarms for multiple Services**, on a given Cluster, for a given application; hence the difference between a Swarm and a Stack is that a Swarm simply applies to a single Service, whereas a Stack manages multiple Swarms and hence multiple Services that all comprise a scalable and distributed application.

So I ask: am I correct in my understanding of these fundamental terms or am I misled in some way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Services: Docker Services are the different components of your application...

A service is a an image docker swarm manages for you. You might ask it to run three instances of this image, and docker swarm will do so (if it can).

[Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) shows you all the different images you can run.

> Cluster: Docker Clusters are when you have a Swarm managing 1+ Services for an application across 2+ Docker Hosts; the Cluster simply refers to all the Docker Hosts where your Service containers are running.

Yeah. A cluster is made up of nodes which are either workers (that run the services), or managers (control the scheduling of services across the nodes). Note that a node can be both a worker and a manager.

I'm still getting my head around managers but I believe you should aim to have an odd number of at least 3 otherwise you can have issues if a manager disappears.

> Compose: Docker Compose is a tool used to manage Services, Swarms and Stacks.

Docker compose is used to combine images into a working application. It might include a front end proxy, a website and a backend database for example. This technology has nothing to do with docker swarm particularly... except you can use it to deploy your application across a swarm (https://codefresh.io/blog/deploy-docker-compose-v3-swarm-mode-cluster/)

> Stack: Docker Stacks occur when a Swarm Manager is managing multiple...

Stack is used for docker cloud. This probably isn't what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks @Ross (+1) - just two (hopefully!) quick followup questions if you don't mind: **(1)** re-reading the docs, are you *sure* that Swarm is *required* to manage a Service? From the docs, it looks like you can just use Compose on a single host to manage multiple service containers, without any involvement of Swarm. Thoughts? And **(2)** are you *sure* Docker Stacks are *only* used by Docker Cloud? Again after re-reading the docs it seems you can have a Stack without Docker Cloud at all. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok. A service only exists within a swarm :) So yes you absolutely need swarm to manage it... however you don't need a swarm to deploy docker images. In fact I strongly suggest you don't until you get used to docker. You are correct - docker compose is a great way to go and works without docker swarm.

2) double checked the docks - stacks do now work with swarm :)

Comment: Would it be correct if we say that docker-compose file defines a stack to be deployed on docker cloud?

Answer (score 7):

Docker swarm is a Clustering and orchestration tool. It is used for scheduling containers across multiple nodes. You can combine multiple nodes as a cluster and then send "docker run" command to this cluster.

Docker stack is a collection of services that make up an application in a specific environment. The extension of stack file is yaml (yml also).

Comment: Thanks @Virendra (+1) - do you know if Docker Stacks can be used outside of Docker Cloud or not? Or are they exclusively used by (and useful for!) Docker Cloud? Thanks again!

Comment: What is then the difference between Stack and Docker Compose? Both of them seem to group a bunch of "services" and run them together.

Comment: @akki docker compose can build images, docker stack can't. Docker stack can deploy multiple replicas and docker compose can't (without workarounds) both can be used outside of docker cloud, but compose is more suited for local environments

Answer (score 4):

**Swarm Mode**: This refers to the overall technology for managing a multi-node environment with declarative syntax. It consists of an embedded raft database distributed across a quorum of managers, and a scheduler that is constantly correcting the difference between the current state and target state defined by the Services.

**Cluster**: A group of nodes managed by Swarm Mode.

**Node**: A single docker engine that is part of the Cluster. Each node may be a Worker or a Manager. Managers can both run a workload and they are responsible for maintaining the raft database and selecting a leader to run the scheduler.

**Stack**: This is mostly treated as a namespace for a collection of services, networks, and volumes deployed within Swarm Mode. At present it's a client side construct that looks for objects with a specific label. A Stack maps to a compose file deployed in Swarm Mode (docker-compose could also be used to deploy a compose file to a single docker engine as a compose project).

**Service**: A definition of an image, the configuration used when deploying it as a container, and where to deploy the containers within a Swarm Mode Cluster. A service may result in one or more containers with the same configuration settings. Swarm Mode will define a DNS entry that is load balanced to the containers with the service name. By combining multiple replicas and rolling updates, changes to the service can be performed without downtime.

Answer (score 2):

I made this to help me understand the stack concept.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Swarm is used to create and manage docker clusters. It prefers host management and service management. Stack relies on the cluster created by swarm, which is just a management tool and tends to service management

[swarm overview](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/)

[stack deploy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/)